# Change the JavaScript function to delete HTML tags, except <br>

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following function that eliminate all the markers of the html code:

```
function saringtags(r, l) {
    for (var e = r.split("<"), n = 0; n < e.length; n++) - 1 != e[n].indexOf(">") && (e[n] = e[n].substring(e[n].indexOf(">") + 1, e[n].length));
    return e = e.join(""), e = e.substring(0, l - 1)
}
```

The problem is that this:

```
<div class="lyric">
<blockquote>
It's nine o'clock on a Saturday<br>
The regular crowd shuffles in<br>
There's an old man sitting next to me<br>
Makin' love to his tonic and gin<br>
</blockquote>
</div>
```

Turns into this:

```
It's nine o'clock on a SaturdayThe regular crowd shuffles inThere's an old man sitting next to meMakin' love to his tonic and gin
```

How to create an exception for the `<br>` marker in the function?
This result is what I need:

```
It's nine o'clock on a Saturday<br>The regular crowd shuffles in<br>There's an old man sitting next to me<br>Makin' love to his tonic and gin
```

Comment: replace all `<br>` with `\n` first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expression:

/<.*[^br]>/g

```
html.replace(/<.*[^br]>/g,'')
```

https://regexr.com/58l77

Comment: This solution works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You've reimplemented `innerText`:

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('lyric')[0].innerText)
```

```html
<div class="lyric">
<blockquote>
It's nine 
o'clock on a 
Saturday<br>
The regular crowd shuffles in<br>
There's an old man <br>sitting next to me<br>
Makin' love to his tonic and gin<br>
</blockquote>
</div>
```

(If you really need `<br>` tags you can replace newline characters with `<br>` afterwards.  This will be much less error-prone than trying to manipulate HTML by regex or other string-manipulation methods.)

Comment: True - but you don't always need <br> where the \n is, and what about <br> where no new line is present? It will be lost.

Comment: @MrAleister `innerText` handles both of those for you; it removes existing newlines from the input HTML and then converts `<br>` and `<p>` to newlines.  I've updated the example to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've been helpful

```
var text = `<div class="lyric"><blockquote>It's nine o'clock on a Saturday<br>The regular crowd shuffles in<br>There's an old man sitting next to me<br>Makin' love to his tonic and gin<br></blockquote></div>"`;

var str = text.replace(/<br>/gi, ' vvvvv ').replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "").replace(/ vvvvv /gi, '<br>');

console.log(str);
```